# Touchpad detected as "PS/2 Logitech Wheel Mouse" on Asus N550JK

Tags: 14.04, touchpad, 15.04, asus, focaltech

On my Asus N550KL laptop (running Ubuntu Gnome 14.04), my touchpad is detected as "PS/2 Logitech Wheel Mouse".

`xinput` outputs:

```
⎡ Virtual core pointer                      id=2    [master pointer  (3)]
⎜   ↳ Virtual core XTEST pointer                id=4    [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ PS/2 Logitech Wheel Mouse                 id=13   [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎣ Virtual core keyboard                     id=3    [master keyboard (2)]
    ↳ Virtual core XTEST keyboard               id=5    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Power Button                              id=6    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Video Bus                                 id=7    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Video Bus                                 id=8    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Sleep Button                              id=9    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ USB2.0 HD UVC WebCam                      id=10   [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Asus WMI hotkeys                          id=11   [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ AT Translated Set 2 keyboard              id=12   [slave  keyboard (3)]
```

Comment: FYI, this is an issue with more Asus laptop models. Last time I looked, a touchpad-specific driver was not yet written for this.

Comment: Thxs for the info, but can't this touchpad work with another touchpad driver? I don't know yet how drivers work and are coded, but I heard that there were just a few ones for a large ammount of existing hardware. Btw, I searched and couldn't find any drivers for ubuntu on the internet, only some sources for archlinux but it didnt compile with dkms build...

Comment: The problem with this specific hardware is that so far nobody has stepped up to write the driver. Does this help? http://askubuntu.com/questions/470388/how-do-i-get-the-touchpad-working-on-an-asus-x450l

Comment: It appears that there is some development activity for this device, see https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=1110011#c125 and https://github.com/mgottschlag/linux/commit/b2d84ebede586a171d0ec57d5a2036d83fd8e4bb for technical details.

Comment: We need to know which touchpad is used. It seems that OP had a Focaltech, but there could be others, like Elantech or Alps.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There seem to be a duplicate of the question here:

[Touchpad not recognized on Asus N550JK - TP500L (FocalTech)](https://askubuntu.com/questions/609892/touchpad-not-recognized-on-asus-n550jk-focaltech)

but since the answer worked for me I will re-post it here:

> I finally came to this bug report:
>   https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/1372609
>
> It seems FocalTech touchpad needs a specific driver, and that work is
>   in progress to integrate it into the mainline kernel.
>
> currently, there seem to be a ppa to get a dkms driver for this
>   touchpad : http://ppa.launchpad.net/hanipouspilot/focaltech-dkms
>
> After trying this, I can confirm the following procedure works :
>
> ```
> 1. add ppa:
>
> `sudo add-apt-repository ppa:hanipouspilot/focaltech-dkms`
>
> 2. update the packages database:
>
> `sudo apt-get update`
>
> 3. install the dkms driver:
>
> `sudo apt-get install focaltech-dkms`
>
> 4. reboot
> ```
>
> The touchpad in now recognized. Two finger scrolling works, for
>   example. Also, the zone where the buttons are won't make the cursor
>   move.
>
> Thanks for the community that retro-engeniered this (Asus just replied
>   "no linux support nor technical information" to a request ! Very bad
>   point to them (see the afore-mentioned bug report)).

*(answered by alci, thanks a lot to you if you are reading me)*

---

I just have a few things to add to this:

First, instead of rebooting, you can just run the following commands:

```
sudo modprobe -r psmouse
sudo modprobe psmouse
```

which will get it working just right =)

**For those running Ubuntu 14.04:**

I have not tested it myself, but the first command (`sudo add-apt-repository ppa:hanipouspilot/focaltech-dkms`) has a very nice verbose and explains the necessary steps for doing that on ubuntu 14.04, with the older kernel version.

Answer (score -1):

Follow this step by step and you will get it working

[Multitouch fix for Alps touchpad](https://nwoki.wordpress.com/2012/10/02/multitouch-fix-for-alps-touchpad/)

Then execute these lines in terminal:

```
sudo update-initramfs -u
```

Comment: I tried following that guide on 12.04, but I got this: `make KERNELRELEASE=3.5.0-23-generic -C /lib/modules/3.5.0-23-generic/build M=/var/lib/dkms/psmouse/alps-1.3/build/src psmouse.ko....(bad exit status: 2)` and then this: `ERROR (dkms apport): binary package for psmouse: alps-dst-0.41 not found` (I have an Asus X453MA)