# Touchpad Scroll doesn t work Asus R510JK

Tags: touchpad

I got ubuntu today and it s pretty nice. I ve set up the wireless card and allmost everything but there still is a thing that bothers me and I am not the only one, I ve read lots of topics with the touchhpad scrol and zoom problem but nothing worked for me. I had lots of different errors when I typed synaptics. The error which shows now is:
(No command 'synaptics' found, did you mean:
 Command 'synaptic' from package 'synaptic' (universe)
synaptics: command not found
)
And if I type snaptic it startes a strange package Manager which has no use for the touchpad....
Any ideeas?
Thanks in advance

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add output of `xinput; dmesg | grep pnp` terminal command. And what is Ubuntu version?

Answer (score 0):

You have a FocalTech touchpad. The drivers are not integrated in the Ubuntu kernel yet. But there is a package that builds a module here:

```
https://launchpad.net/~hanipouspilot/+archive/ubuntu/focaltech-dkms
```

You can try instructions here:

```
http://askubuntu.com/questions/609892/touchpad-not-recognized-on-asus-n550jk-focaltech
```

Comment: How do you know it is Focaltech? It may be an Elantech as well.

Comment: @Pilot6 I can double check tonight. What is the best way to check? And if it's Elantech is there any way to make it work? BTW thank you for your work on these drivers! ;-)

Comment: The best way is `dmesg | grep pnp`.