# FocalTech Touchpad not working after resuming from suspend

Tags: touchpad, asus, xinput

My touchpad on Asus X455LF-WX055T works perfectly when I first boot Ubuntu but it does not work whenever I wake it up after suspending it.

Before I suspend, my `xinput list` contains `PS/2 FocalTech FocalTech Touchpad`:

```
xinput
⎡ Virtual core pointer                      id=2    [master pointer  (3)]
⎜   ↳ Virtual core XTEST pointer                id=4    [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ Logitech K270                             id=10   [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ Logitech M315/M235                        id=11   [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ PS/2 FocalTech FocalTech Touchpad         id=15   [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎣ Virtual core keyboard                     id=3    [master keyboard (2)]
    ↳ Virtual core XTEST keyboard               id=5    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Power Button                              id=6    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Video Bus                                 id=7    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Video Bus                                 id=8    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Sleep Button                              id=9    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ USB2.0 VGA UVC WebCam                     id=12   [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Asus WMI hotkeys                          id=13   [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ AT Translated Set 2 keyboard              id=14   [slave  keyboard (3)]
```

When i wake it up after suspending it, my `xinput list` does not contain `PS/2 FocalTech FocalTech Touchpad` but it was replaced(?) by `AT Raw Set 2 keyboard id=15 [slave  keyboard (3)]` which was not present before I suspend:

```
xinput
⎡ Virtual core pointer                      id=2    [master pointer  (3)]
⎜   ↳ Virtual core XTEST pointer                id=4    [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ Logitech K270                             id=10   [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ Logitech M315/M235                        id=11   [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎣ Virtual core keyboard                     id=3    [master keyboard (2)]
    ↳ Virtual core XTEST keyboard               id=5    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Power Button                              id=6    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Video Bus                                 id=7    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Video Bus                                 id=8    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Sleep Button                              id=9    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ USB2.0 VGA UVC WebCam                     id=12   [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Asus WMI hotkeys                          id=13   [slave  keyboard (4)]
    ↳ AT Translated Set 2 keyboard              id=14   [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ AT Raw Set 2 keyboard                     id=15   [slave  keyboard (3)]
```

### What I have tried

#### From ["Touchpad doesn't work after suspend"](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2182922)

I have tried creating a file `/etc/pm/sleep.d/0000trackpad` with the contents:

```
#!/bin/sh
case "$1" in
    resume)
        DISPLAY=:0.0 su USER -c '/usr/bin/synclient TouchpadOff=0' ;;
esac
```

and

```
#!/bin/sh
case "$1" in
    suspend|hibernate)
        modprobe -r psmouse ;;
    resume|thaw)
        modprobe psmouse ;;
esac
```

but both does not work.

#### From ["How do I get the touchpad working on an Asus x450L?"](https://askubuntu.com/questions/470388/how-do-i-get-the-touchpad-working-on-an-asus-x450l)

Adding a Kernel Boot Parameter `psmouse.proto=bare` in `/etc/default/grub` like so:

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash psmouse.proto=bare
```

and then updating grub with `sudo update-grub` but still does not work.

My BIOS is also up-to-date.

Comment: Report this bug to Launchpad. It is hardware specific.

Comment: First try to upgrade UEFI firmware of the laptop.

Comment: @Pilot6 There is already a similar bug in Launchpad [here](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/1504445) but still no solutions for Ubuntu 16.04 LTS. I tried finding how to upgrade UEFI firmware of my laptop, but I can't find any. I found [this](http://www.asus.com/microsite/2014/MB/New_4th_gen_Intel_processor_compatibility/#updater) from ASUS but it just tells me "Visit the ASUS website, at www.asus.com/support then download the relevant BIOS file for your motherboard." which I already did to update my BIOS.

Comment: UEFI firmware is the same as BIOS.

Comment: Does running `sudo modprobe -r psmouse; sleep 1; sudo modprobe psmouse` enable the touchpad?

Comment: @Pilot6 unfortunately not

Comment: This looks like a firmware bug to me. What is the Ubuntu version?

Comment: @Pilot6 Ubuntu 16.04 LTS

Comment: This is some hardware/firmware bug that the kernel can't work around. I suggest reporting a new bug. I have the same touchpad, and there are no issues with suspend.